# How to play a simple system sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio

I just need to play a simple sound, I have app that send messages, and I need to play "message sent" system sound when message get sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I play the system tock sound. As simple as could be. Just find the name of the sound you are trying to play.

Don't forget to import `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` 
And add `AVFoundation.framework` in target's build phases.

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit"] pathForResource:@"Tock" ofType:@"aiff"]] error:NULL];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Do I need to include the sound file, or it's already exist in the system?

Comment: If its a system file then you won't need. Like I did with Tock I just referenced it from the UIKit bundle which is on all devices. So if you actually find the file for the message sent and its not just a file exclusive to the mail.app but the whole system then you'll be able to reference it without including it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` in the iOS [System Sound Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Not available in Swift (Swift 3)  :(